Approve little snitch (alert mode) popup via SSH
Is it possible to approve a new little-snitch (alert mode) popup remotely to unblock the suspended process ?

In detail:

I have an SSH / VPN from, from my iPad to the Mac. The mac is home, not physically accessible.
Some commands that I type on the iPad (that are hence executed on the mac at home) are suspended by little snitch, e.g. ping www.google.com.
Since I am not home, I cannot click the "Allow" rule.

How do I either turn off little snitch on the mac temporarily or approve the connection?
I have only an SSH access to the mac.

Note: I know little snitch has a command line mode, but AFAIK you have to enable it graphically first.


Doesn't allow disabling the popup from remote kind of defeats its purpose?

I found a solution, but it only works after you once enabled command line mode, which requires physical access.

Enable Little Snitch command line mode.

LittleSnitch → Settings → Security → Check the Allow Access via Terminal option.


Issue a command that is known to be blocked when in Alert Mode, by little snitch popup on the host.
E.g. connect via SSH to the Mac and run a ping www.google.com
It will not work, because there now is a popup, so the ping results in a “Request timeout”.

SSH to the Mac, and temporarily disable the firewall. Switch it right on again afterwards


sudo littlesnitch write-preference activeSilentMode 1
sudo littlesnitch write-preference activeSilentMode 0

The ping command is now unblocked. Your firewall is still in Alert Mode. Repeat process if needed.

This is as if you had clicked Allow Once in the Little Snitch popup.


The OP mentions quite clearly the need to use Little Snitch command line mode. Your answer does not give any information the OP doesn't already know.

Self-answering is fine, but how does this overcome the problem described in the question (which mentions lack of physical access)?

As OP I can confidently say that this solves my problem and provides the information needed. I was aware of the command line option, but I did not know how to enable, or what steps are necessary afterwards to overcome the popup. This answer provides the practical instructions to render a potential path an actual solution. Once command line options enabled, I can remotely unblock suspended processes. Enabling command line is a step I only need to do once (yes, this does require physical access once) - but  then I can remotely unblock. I would have accepted it as well from any other contributor.
